# Python - Edit specific cell in CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have created a quiz game in Python that also contains a login and register program however I'm trying to add a scoring system.

Currently, I have the CSV file set out like this:

```
username,password,score
```

When you create an account the score is set to 0 and is loaded when you log in using:

```
for row in users:
     if username == row[0]:
         currentScore = row[2]
         currentScore = int((currentScore))
```

This grabs the users high score from the CSV file.
However when a game finishes I have this setup to determine if their new score is higher than there old score or not:

```
if int(score) > int(currentScore):
    currentscore = score
```

I then need it to open the database and find the user that is playing and update there score with the new one. How would I do this? I have tried to get csv to edit a certain row but it doesn't seem to work.

Full code can be found here:https://pastebin.com/q07qazJA

Comment: `then need it to open the database`, and which database would that be? a csv isn't a database, why not just use `sqlite` since it comes in the standard lib. will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: I you don't want to deal with sql use a `.json` file. You can treat the data as a dict instead of needing to loop through all the data. A dict is hashed allowing for easier lookups, otherwise I'd suggest using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to make your life easier with the csv file.

Comment: Why don't you use **pandas** for this? It's really an awesome package.

Comment: Pandas is a really awesome package, but it comes with a high overhead. Using it only to read/write a csv file is unsane on a efficiency point of view. Remember that sentence: *if your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

```
if int(score) > int(currentScore):
    currentscore = score

    r = csv.reader(open('users.csv'))
    lines = list(r)
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        if [username, password] == list(line):
            break
    lines[n] = username, password, score

    writer = csv.writer(open('users.csv', 'w'))
    writer.writerows(lines)

quiz = False
```

Explanation: Editing a row will need to be done in two steps since it's not practical to read and write to the same line of the file, so first open the `csv` file, read and save the data it to a list, edit the list, then open the file *again* to write the edited list back to the `csv`.