# Editing a CSV file (reading and writing at the same time)

Tags: python, csv

My program needs to search through a database untill the correct user is found. Once the user has been found, the 4th column needs to be edited.

I have currently got the function which reads the CSV file and finds the users name.

```
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
        reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
        for row in reader:
            if stop:
                break
            for field in row:
                if row[0] == user_namev2 and row[1] == user_passwordv2:
                    #add user_weight to column 4
```

This is as far as i have got. The research i conducted told me that opening the file in write mode will remove all its remaining contents, so any ideas how to get around this issue.

For clarity:
`user_namev2` contains the username of the user
`user_passwordv2` contains the password of the user

**EDIT:**

I have used one of the answers given however am having trouble with implementation. The code goes as follows:

```
user_information = [['dom', 'dom', '70', 'strong'],[['Bench Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Bench Press'],['test', 'test']]]

def Changer(user_information, weight):
    r = csv.reader(open('AccountsTest.csv'))
    username = user_information[0][0]
    password = user_information[0][1]
    lines = list(r)
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        if [username, password] == list(line):
            break
    print (lines[n])
```

This should retrieve the user dom from my database. Instead, it retrieves the last user from the database. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: probably do the editing in two steps: first open and read the file into a data structure, a `list` probably easiest, and edit the value within the list -- then write out the list of new data to the `csv` file.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how i could do this?

Comment: Sure, here's an example from a previous answer I wrote [Python - Edit specific cell in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358227/1248974)

Comment: Perfect thanks! I will try implementing this to my program tomorrow. If i have any issues I will let you know. thank you again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Edit specific cell in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357566/python-edit-specific-cell-in-csv-file)

Comment: I am having trouble with implementation. I have edited my question to show my troubles

Comment: Please add a sample CSV file to your question (e.g. 5 rows worth and the header if present)

Comment: Are you sure it is printing the *last* user in the database? Only if the `username, password` you are searching for are the last entry in the database should it do that, at least that's what my answer does that I linked you to.